# Access the elements of a multidimensional array through a pointer in another class

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a `int costMap[20][20];` inside a `dialog` class.

Inside that class I am making an object from another class called `pathFind`

```
int costMap[20][20];
//costMap is filled with values (that represent the cost for each node -> pathFinder)
int (*firstElement)[20] = costMap;
pathFind *finder = new pathFind(*firstElement);
```

I would like to be able to acces the values of the multidimensional array inside the `pathFind` class

```
int (*costMap)[20];

pathFind::pathFind(int *map){
    costMap = &map;
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work. I get an "cannot convert int** to int(*)[20] error.

**Question**: How can you access the elements of a multidimensional array through a pointer in another class

Comment: Class names may not have `.` in them.

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
pathFind::pathFind(int (*map)[20] ){
    costMap = map;
}
```

That is, *match* the types!

Also note that `T (*)[N]` and `T**` are not compatible types. One cannot convert to other. In your code, you're trying to do that, which is what the error message tells you.

Besides, there are other issues with your code, such as you should *avoid* using `new` and raw-pointers. Use `std::vector` or other containers from the Standard library, and when you need pointer, prefer using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` whichever suits your need.

Comment: It's not really an `also`. It's the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write

```
pathFind::pathFind(int (*map)[20]){ ... }
```

but this being *C++* you may find this better:

```
template< std::size_t N, std::size_t M >
pathFind::pathFind(int (&map)[N][M]){ ... }
```

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: True, thank you. That goes to show I would never do something like that

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> pathFind::pathFind(int *map){
> ```

This expects a pointer to an integer.

Elsewhere, you've already discovered the correct type to use:

```
pathFind::pathFind(int (*map)[20]){
```

Try to avoid this pointer hackery, though.